# Sql query troubleshoot with DateModified and Date Created

Tags: sql

So I have a record which it's status can be changed. The initial statuses are application, Committed, Closed Deal the final couple status aren't always the same but the main importance is Closed Deal. I'm trying to create a query that determines if the record was in closed deal status during the date parameters StartDate and EndDate. The record has a Created and Modified Column. Modified is automatically set to be Created date until another status is added.

For Example:

```
Loan    Status           Created     Modified    IsCurrent
 1      Application      2015-01-01  2015-01-01  true
```

Trigger next status update February 1st 2015*

```
Loan    Status           Created     Modified    IsCurrent
 1      Application     2015-01-01  2015-02-01   false
 1      Committed       2015-02-01  2015-02-01   true
```

I can write the query to find the records that closed deal have been created or modified during the date parameters and records that are current that have been created before the Start Date parameter. I'm having trouble querying the records where creation date was before start date and the next status after closed deal was added after the End Date Parameter.

For Example

```
StartDate = 2015-01-01
EndDate   = 2015-04-01
Loan    Status           Created     Modified    IsCurrent
 1      Application     2014-10-01  2014-11-01   false
 1      Committed       2014-11-01  2014-11-01   false
 1      Closed Deal     2014-12-01  2015-05-01   false
 1      Paid Off        2015-05-01  2015-05-01   true
```

My Current Query

```
select * from LoanStatusHistories
join LoanStatus on LoanStatusHistories.LoanStatus_Id = Loanstatus.Id
where LoanStatus.Value = 'Closed Deal' and 
      ((LoanStatusHistories.Created >= '2015-01-01' and 
      LoanStatusHistories.Modified <= '2015-04-01' ) or
      IsCurrent = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that a status change always results in creating a new LoanStatus, right? Then you need only to focus on the Created field. I also would assume the value of "IsCurrent" as irrelevant for your use case.

```
select * from LoanStatusHistories
join LoanStatus on LoanStatusHistories.LoanStatus_Id = Loanstatus.Id
where LoanStatus.Value = 'Closed Deal' and 
      ((LoanStatusHistories.Created >= '2015-01-01' and 
      LoanStatusHistories.Created<= '2015-04-01' ))
```

if you want to check both mentioned states:

```
LoanStatus.Value in ('Closed Deal', 'Committed')
```

EDIT:  Do you also have the Value field in the LoanStatusHistories table? if yes, use this instead. If not, you won´t be able to get deals that were commited/closed and set to another state later on. Is that possible? "paid" after "committed"?

Comment: this does not work. The example I gave, the date for Closed Deal is '2014-12-01' which does not fall inbetween start date and end date. Iscurrent is very valuable. It determines which of the old records are still in close deal status. A record with the current status of Closed deal where date modified and created  was '2014-01-01' will be picked up by the query